# How to increase \textheight, without changing the topmargin

Tags: koma-script, geometry, typearea

Using `KOMA-script` classes I'd like to increase the `\textheight` of my text area. I can do so with the command `\areaset{\textwidth}{1.1\textheight}` of KOMA-script's native `typearea` package.

However, in this case, both the top and bottom "margins" are decreased in order to increase the body area.

What I'd like, is to increase the `\textheight` *without modifying the top margin*, or in other words, by adding space to the body area *from the bottom only*.

[image]

How can I achieve that?

---

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,DIV=10]{scrartcl}
    \usepackage{typearea}
%       \areaset{\textwidth}{1.2\textheight}
    \usepackage{showframe}  
\begin{document}
    Hello world!
\end{document}
```

Comment: Using `typearea` the ratio of top and bottom margin will be about 1:2 (see chapter "Construction fo the Page Layout with typearea"). If you have other requirements regarding the margins use package `geometry`.

Comment: @esdd I've actually found an easier solution! (see below)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since the "blocs" (header, text area, footer) constituting the page are defined relatively the one to the other beginning from the upper left (or upper inner in case of double sided document) corner, the solution is actually stunningly easy:

I want a bigger `\textheight`? Just increase it via **`\setlength{\textheight}{1.1\textheight}`**!

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,DIV=10]{scrartcl}
    \usepackage[]{showframe}    
    \setlength{\textheight}{1.1\textheight}

\begin{document}
    Hello world!
\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent solution. Does this only work with KOMA classes?

Comment: @FaheemMitha No, it works with all classes: `\textheight` isn't a KOMA-specific command.

Comment: Well, it's a handy construction. TeX (or maybe LaTeX?) wastes a lot of space at the bottom of the page by default. And I don't off-hand know any other way to deal with it.